# Convert .net user control to COM component

Tags: com, user-controls, com-interop

I have a **working .net winform user control** and would like to convert it to COM. I've been struggling finding a way to convert this user control **to be COM enabled** (for use in VS6/C++6). I'm not sure if this is do-able? Or I have to think about a different approach? Here's the interface:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("C8BDB591-189D-4EB5-A026-7C9FFBEE3A85")]
public interface iMainInterface
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void ShowMyInterface();
}
```

And here's the control:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(iMainInterface))]
[Guid("F8D26781-5A97-4467-B732-7EAB1A04C3F2")]
public partial class MainInterface : UserControl
{
    public void ShowMyInterface()
    {
       ...
    }
 }
```

The error message seems to be for **[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(iMainInterface))]**

Here's the error:
Error   2   Cannot register assembly "MyInterface.dll". Type 'xxx.MainInterface' does not support the specified default COM interface: 'xxx.iMainInterface' PerformReportControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ComSourceInterfaces] should only be used for interfaces that generate events.  It sure doesn't look like iMainInterface has any events so just remove the attribute.

You forgot to have your class inherit the interface.  Fix:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("F8D26781-5A97-4467-B732-7EAB1A04C3F2")]
public partial class MainInterface : UserControl, iMainInterface
{
    public void ShowMyInterface()
    {
       ...
    }
 }
```

Do favor a capital I (not i) for interface types.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes a second set of eyes help me big time